# mongodb terminated and won't come back up. Error 13532

Tags: mongodb

Running mongodb 2.6.4 on Win2008-R2.
Full of data.... and today it went down, and won't come back up.

What to do?

```
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 Service running
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1864 port=27017 dbpath=c:\MongoDB\Data 64-bit host=619723-MONGO-1
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\MongoDB\mongod.cfg", service: true, storage: { dbPath: "c:\MongoDB\Data", directoryPerDB: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "c:\MongoDB\logs" } }
2015-01-27T02:03:58.890-0600 [initandlisten] journal dir=c:\MongoDB\Data\journal
2015-01-27T02:03:58.968-0600 [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13532 unexpected file in journal directory c:\MongoDB\Data\journal : j._1895 : can't find its preceding file
2015-01-27T02:03:58.984-0600 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13532 unexpected file in journal directory c:\MongoDB\Data\journal : j._1895 : can't find its preceding file, terminating
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Was there any useful info in `c:\MongoDB\logs`?

Comment: The error message is somewhat self-explanatory, although the recovery action is perhaps non-obvious. If you restart `mongod` and journal files are found (leftover from an unclean shutdown), these will be replayed in order. It seems that however your `mongod` process was terminated, the files in the journal directory are not as expected and recovery cannot continue. Your data files may be in an inconsistent state depending on what happened when `mongod` shutdown, so the normal course of action would be to repair (or ideally re-sync from a known good node if you are running a replica set).

Comment: In the normal case automatic recovery from the journal is possible (and expected) after unclean shutdown. To understand what may have gone wrong in your specific situation some more information on how/why `mongod` shutdown might be helpful. For example, was there a server assertion, power failure, hardware errors, lack of disk space, etc. Repairing the database may get you back online, but it would be better to understand the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, google did not seem to have anything useful on mongo error 13532

What we did:

a) Deleted all files in /journal dir

b) Deleted the mongo .lock file

c) From cmd line: mongod --repair --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\

d) Started up mongo service

Up now for several hours OK.
Not sure what the data loss was.