# mongodb: Journal error. Which collection is referred to?

Tags: mongodb

We have two collections.

So I have to delete at least one, because mongo won't restart (losing 400gb of data in the process, but that is normal when using mongo).

From this log, I cannot tell which one to delete. Is there a clue I am missing?

```
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 Service running
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1864 port=27017 dbpath=c:\MongoDB\Data 64-bit host=619723-MONGO-1
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-01-27T02:03:58.781-0600 [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\MongoDB\mongod.cfg", service: true, storage: { dbPath: "c:\MongoDB\Data", directoryPerDB: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "c:\MongoDB\logs" } }
2015-01-27T02:03:58.890-0600 [initandlisten] journal dir=c:\MongoDB\Data\journal
2015-01-27T02:03:58.968-0600 [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13532 unexpected file in journal directory c:\MongoDB\Data\journal : j._1895 : can't find its preceding file
2015-01-27T02:03:58.984-0600 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13532 unexpected file in journal directory c:\MongoDB\Data\journal : j._1895 : can't find its preceding file, terminating
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-01-27T02:03:58.999-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb terminated and won't come back up. Error 13532](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179522/mongodb-terminated-and-wont-come-back-up-error-13532)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our plan was to reset the databases, but we did a repair instead.